# Prevent Jade from flattening folder structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, pug

I've been attempting to implement a build solution using NPM scripts as opposed to Gulp/Grunt/etc as outlined here: http://substack.net/task_automation_with_npm_run and here: http://blog.keithcirkel.co.uk/how-to-use-npm-as-a-build-tool/. However, I'm struggling to integrate a clean and sensible approach for managing numerous Jade files in the build process.

The Jade CLI supports passing it a directory and outputting all of the deeply nested compiled Jade files. This is great, however, this completely flattens the folder structure. I'd ideally like to have Jade output the results whilst maintaining the directory structure. What's the best way to go about this?

Example folder structure:

```
package.json
src/
  foo.jade
  bar/
    baz.jade
    qux.jade
```

Running `jade src -o build` outputs:

```
package.json
build/
  foo.html
  baz.hmtl
  qux.html
src/
```

Instead of:

```
package.json
build/
  foo.html
  bar/
    baz.html
    qux.html
src/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how I missed this but for anyone who should happen upon this in the future, the `-H` flag is your friend.

ex: `jade src -H -o build`

ref: https://github.com/jadejs/jade-cli/blob/master/index.js#L36